# The Local Security Authority Cannot Be Contacted when attempting to login to any RDP session from a workstation

Tags: windows, remote, desktop

I have, what seems to be, a very unique situation happening here.

At one stage RDP Connections were working perfectly, until one day, it literally just stopped. The user now encounters the exact same error when attempting to logon to any Remote Server, the error being "An authentication error has occurred. The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted. Remote computer x.x.x.x"

I have found many, many workarounds for this error, but all of them indicate that the server needs adjustments. Here's why I think that this is only related to the workstation itself, and not the server.

1. It's only happening on this machine
2. All other users can login from their respective machines
3. This user can login from other machines
4. We have attempted to login to 4 different Remote Servers, all providing the same message. Each of these has different configs, but are accessible by other workstations.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated and helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This error message can occur when you've enabled (or Windows Updates enabled for you?) Extensible Authentication Protocol-Transport Level Security (EAP-TLS) and the server certificate has a key that's less than 464 bits.  [This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813550/-the-local-security-authority-cannot-be-contacted-error-0x80090304-when-you-try-to-connect-to-a-remote-access-server) has other causes for this error message, but you didn't mention VPN use or returning from standby.

If so, the suggested workaround is to configure the server with a key length that's greater than 464 bits.